# Show that $e^{ta}=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_\alpha}\frac{e^{\lambda t}}{\lambda-a}\,d\lambda$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

This is the exercise 18 on page 359 of *Analysis II* of Amann and Escher. I'm stuck in this exercise

> Suppose $a\in\Bbb C$ and $\alpha\neq\Re(a)$. Show that for $\gamma_\alpha:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C,\,s\mapsto \alpha+is$ we have $$e^{ta}=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_\alpha}\frac{e^{\lambda t}}{\lambda-a}\,d\lambda\quad\text{for }t>0\tag1$$ (HINT: the Cauchy integral formula gives $$e^{ta}=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\Bbb D(a,r)}\frac{e^{\lambda t}}{\lambda-a}\,d\lambda\quad\text{for }t\in\Bbb R\text{ and }r>0\tag2$$ Now apply the Cauchy integral theorem.)

Trying to follow the hint I tried to create a family of closed paths $\Gamma_r=[\gamma_r]+[\delta_r]$, such that $a$ doesn't belong to it bounded regions, and then use the Cauchy integral theorem, that is

$$\int_{\Gamma_r}g(\lambda)\, d\lambda=0\quad r>0$$

for $g(\lambda):=\frac{e^{\lambda t}}{\lambda-a}$, and exploit some kind of symmetry to relate the integration on the paths $[\gamma_r]$ or $[\delta_r]$ to the Cauchy integral formula. By example, without lose of generality suppose that $\alpha>\Re(a)$, then I could define

$$\gamma_r:[-r,r]\to\Bbb C,\quad s\mapsto \alpha+is\\\delta_r:[r,r+\pi]\to\Bbb C,\quad s\mapsto re^{-i(s-r-\pi/2)}\tag3$$

and try to relate the integration on the half circle defined by $\delta_r$ with the integral in the complete circle, where for suitable enough big $r$ I can use the Cauchy integral formula. However this is not easy to deal with, because it don't show a symmetry to exploit.

Maybe I'm over-complicating and the exercise want to do something different. Can someone help me?

---

**EDIT:**

It can be shown that $(1)$, as an improper integral of Riemann, converges conditionally, and after some changes of variables the question reduces to show that

$$\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_r}\frac{e^\zeta}{\zeta}\,d\zeta=1$$

where $\gamma_r:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C,\, t\mapsto r+it$
for any chosen $r\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. Graphing the integrand we can see that it describes two non-rectifiable spirals (symmetric respect to the real axis) that converges to some point on the real axis.

Comment: Cauchy's Integral Formula doesn't just hold true for disks - in general, if you have *any* domain in which $f$ is analytic, we can determine the values of $f$ inside the domain purely from the values of $f$ on the boundry. We can use a more homotopic form of the Cauchy Integral Formula to show this. Your question is simply an edge case of this idea

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I know what you said but this doesnt help me with the question. You mean that there is a poligonal $\Gamma$ easier to relate to the Cauchy integral formula?

Comment: What does $\alpha\neq\Re(a)$ mean? How is the integral defined on that contour? I presume you are using an improper integral?

Comment: Well, I would generally think the rectangle form of the CIF is the easiest to use for simple cases like this, but that isn't going to help you solve this problem using the hint. Also, what is $\alpha$ here? Some arbitrary real number? And how do $\alpha$ and $a$ relate?

Comment: @copper.hat I pressume the same. The exercise doesn't says something more. I guess the integral is on the ray defined by $\gamma_\alpha$ that it defines an improper integral of Riemann

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen this is all the exercise says. I will edit the question to add where I get it.

Comment: Nothing leaps out at me here.

Comment: I can solve this directly (using the Fourier transform) but for the life of me cannot see a suitable contour to use Cauchy.

Comment: @copper.hat thank you, but in the context of the book this is not possible, the Fourier transforms are shown in the next (and last) chapter of the book.

Comment: Bump. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also confused by this problem.

But I suspect that the problem is wrong. Please see the following.
$$
\begin{aligned}
e^{ta}&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_\alpha} e^{\lambda t}(\lambda -a)^{-1}  d \lambda\\
\iff 1&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_\alpha} \frac{e^{(\lambda-a) t}}{(\lambda -a)} d\lambda \qquad &&\eta=t(\lambda-a)\\
\iff 1&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_\beta} \frac{e^{\eta}}{\eta} d\eta \qquad &&\gamma_\beta=\phi(\gamma_\alpha), \qquad \phi:x\mapsto t(x-a).
\end{aligned}$$
Here note that the line $\gamma_\alpha=\alpha+ i \mathbb R$ and $\gamma_\beta=t(\alpha-a)+ i \mathbb R$.

If $\gamma_\beta$ is right to $0$, then we only need to consider the left half circle $$\gamma_1: [0,\pi]\to \mathbb C,\quad t\mapsto \beta +i Re^{it}.$$
Here $\beta$ is the center of the circle on the line $\gamma_\beta$.
$$\begin{aligned}
&\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{e^{\eta}}{\eta} d\eta\\
=&\int_0^\pi\frac{e^{\beta+i Re^{it}}\cdot (-R e^{it})}{\beta+i Re^{it}}dt \to 0,\quad R\to \infty.
\end{aligned}$$
Just as @Masacroso answered.
This part is checked by computer.

---

But the rest is also checked by computer to be wrong.

If $\gamma$ is left to $0$, that is $Re( \alpha -a)<0$, then we need to consider the right half circle
$$\gamma_2: [0,\pi]\to \mathbb C,\quad t\mapsto \beta -i Re^{it}.$$
Here
$$\begin{aligned}
&\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{e^{\eta}}{\eta} d\eta\\
=&\int_0^\pi\frac{e^{\beta-i Re^{it}}\cdot (R e^{it})}{\beta-i Re^{it}}dt\to 2\pi i,\quad R\to \infty
\end{aligned}$$
It is also checked by computer directly that $e^{ta}\neq \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_\alpha} e^{\lambda t}(\lambda -a)^{-1}  d \lambda$ when $Re(\alpha -a)<0$.

Comment: I will check it carefully, with due time. Maybe I overlooked that it will be different depending on the position of the vertical ray (maybe in the time I did this exercise I thought that any solution, with the ray to the left or right of zero, will be the same)

Comment: using numerical computations seems that the integral is zero independent of the choice of the vertical path. Also the dubious algebraic solution of Wolfram Mathematica says that the answer is ever zero. Im computing and testing the integral $\int_\gamma z^{-1}e^z dz$ where $\gamma:= a+ i\mathbb{R}$ for $a\neq 0$, being negative or positive.

Comment: @Masacroso Yes, it depends on relative the position of $\alpha$ and $a$. When $\alpha$ is right to $a$, it is $e^{ta}$. When $\alpha$ is left to $a$, it is exactly $0$. That is my computation using also Mathematica.